# Who Cut Pipeline confusion

Tags: shell, unix, pipeline, cut

I am trying to understand what this command does.

who | cut  –c1-8

Is it displaying the first 8 characters of details of users logged in?

Or is it displaying the first 8 people who are logged in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cut -c1-8` will display the first 8 characters of each line of its standard input. The full pipeline will thus display the first 8 characters of details of all users logged in.